# How to use C# and Reflection to get Implemented Class type not the Interface type

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

**UPDATE:** My "problem" was due to a bad assumption about the class I was using reflection upon.  My question below is nonsensical as it doesn't act that way.  But I am leaving it here in case the code snippet is useful.

I am using reflection to generate viewmodels off of a compiled class that resides in a **separate** assembly.  Most everything is working except the types I get back from the compiled assembly shows an interface instead of the class that is the concrete implementation of the interface.

For example, in the compiled assembly I define a property like:

```
    public List<String> strings { get; set; }
```

Using reflection, I have been able to generate a corresponding property (and complete class) that looks like this:

```
    public ICollection<String> strings { get; set; }
```

I get the types doing this (severely snipped for brevity):

```
    Type value = <...some passed in type...>
    String types = String.Join(",", value.GetGenericArguments().Select(t => t.Name).ToArray());

    String.Format("{0}<{1}>", value.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), types);
```

Is there any way using the Type object to determine what concrete implementation was used for the interface returned?  I am guessing no but thought I would ask.

If there is not a way, I am thinking of using a "most likely implementation" look up for a given interface (i.e. you pass in "ICollection", I translate that into a concrete "List") unless there is a better suggestion???

A "perfect" solution isn't necessarily required as this is used to generate Controllers, Views, and ViewModels (with automapper and Kendo UI) using T4 templates.  So if there are a few things to clean up, that is fine.  So any suggestions that get me close are welcome.

Comment: You could always check the likely suspects. For example, `if (value is List<String>)` ...

Comment: After probably 5 hours looking and after posting this question, I realized I am an **idiot**.  I **assumed** my `List` was coming over as `ICollection` because `List` implements `ICollection` and because I almost always use a `List` in the scenario.  Turns out, in the class I was working with, I declared it as `ICollection` not `List` and therefore was coming over the "wrong way".  When I discovered this, I flipped my type and it comes over as expected, I can recreate the model as a viewmodel and all is good with the world.  Too bad I didn't look at the actual implementation sooner.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, i played with reflection a little bit and here what I came with:

```
    //Initial list with ints
    var items = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    //ICollection<int> reference
    var collectionOfItems = (ICollection<int>) items;

    //...

    //First of, get collection Type object
    var collectionType = collectionOfItems.GetType();
    //Next, let's grab generic arguments
    var genericArguments = collectionType.GetGenericArguments();

    //For each generic candidate type we need to construct it with collection's generic arguments
    var candidate = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericArguments);

    //Perform check
    if (collectionType.IsAssignableFrom(candidate))
        Console.WriteLine("Can be casted to {0}", candidate);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot be cated to {0}", candidate);
```

Yes, it's possible with reflection , but you need to check against a lot of possible types (some not BCL type can also implement `ICollection`).
Better just declare properties with concrete types